# Set convergence in Erdős and Kac (1940)

Tags: number-theory

Here is a section from The Probabilistic Method by Alon and Spencer. For reference, $v(n)$ denotes the number of primes $p$ dividing $n$. $X_p$ takes the value $1$ if $p$ divides $x$ and $0$ otherwise. Note: I don't think it is necessary to understand everything below to understand my question.

[image: The Probabilistic Method (4th), Alon and Spencer, pg. 48]

My question has to do with the line, "so that it suffices to show Theorem 4.2.2. with $v$ replaced by $X$." Without going into what we are actually proving, the claim is that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n} \left| 
\left\{  x:1 \le x \le n, v(x) - s(n) \ge \ln \ln n + \lambda (\ln \ln n)^{1/2} \right\}    \right| = \int_{\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-t^2/2}  dt$$
implies
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n} \left| 
\left\{  x:1 \le x \le n, v(x) \ge \ln \ln n + \lambda (\ln \ln n)^{1/2} \right\}    \right| = \int_{\lambda}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-t^2/2}  dt$$
where $s(n) = o((\ln \ln n)^{1/2})$.
It seems to me that this is true iff as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $$\left\{  x:1 \le x \le n, v(x) - s(n) \ge \ln \ln n + \lambda (\ln \ln n)^{1/2} \right\} = \left\{  x:1 \le x \le n, v(x) \ge \ln \ln n + \lambda (\ln \ln n)^{1/2} \right\}$$
In turn, it seems to me that this is true iff for all sufficiently large $n$, there does not exist $1 \le x \le n$ such that $$\ln \ln n + \lambda (\ln \ln n)^{1/2} \le v(x) < \ln \ln n + \lambda (\ln \ln n)^{1/2} + s(n)$$
since if such an $x$ did exist, it would be in the second set above but not the first one. I don't see how I can prove this latter statement. Maybe my entire approach is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!